# Maxima: Method rk and draw3d not working properly

Tags: math, maxima

I have been following a basic manual of Maxima, I need to solve a differencial ecuation system.

First of all, I loaded both of the packets, load(dynamics); and load(draw);

In order to obtain the points I have:

```
solutionsPoints: rk([4-x^2-4*y^2,y^2-x^2+1],[x,y],[-1.25,0.75],[t,0,4,0.02]);
```

I got all the points needed, now to represent this,

```
draw3d(points_joined = true, point_type = dot, points(solutionsPoints), terminal = eps);
```

Maxima in this case returns:

```
[gr3d(points)]
```

What should I do to have this representation?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you have `terminal = eps`, therefore `draw3d` will create a .eps file and it won't display the image. I tried `draw3d` as you showed it, and it created `maxima_out.eps` in the current directory, and I can use a viewer (I used `evince`) to look at it, and it seems OK.

If you cut out the `terminal = eps` part, it will display the curve immediately, without creating an output file.